# How to calculate cost basis for list of incongruent batches of buy and sell transactions (forex trading)

Tags: foreign-exchange, cryptocurrency, portfolio, cost-basis, tracking

How can I calculate the cost basis for my forex portfolio at any given time?

I'm trying to build a spreadsheet to track forex trading of cryptocurrency pairs. Specifically I'm looking at XMR-BTC

- https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/XMR-BTC/

I'm not using any derivitives or limit orders. The idea is farily simple: Buy Monero (XMR)
with Bitcoin (BTC) when the price is low. Sell Monero (XMR) for Bitcoin (BTC) when the price is high.

I want my spreadsheet to tell me something fairly simple: what's the average price (in BTC) that I've spent on Monero so far? This is very simple when you have only made a few purchases. It's also fairly simple when you've made sells of exactly the same quantity of your buys. But when you have a bunch of different buys and sells of different quantities, this is non-trivial.

As best I can tell, there is no precise way to measure this. There's many, including:

1. FIFO
2. LIFO
3. High Cost
4. Low Cost
5. Average Cost
6. Specific Identifier
7. Others??

So my question is, how can I calculate the cost basis of my portfolio at any point in the following set of transactions.

> **Note** I'm not just interested in knowing how to determine the cost basis at the *end* of this set of transactions. I want to understand how to calculate the cost basis after *every* step of the following transactions.
>
> I'm also not interested in tracking the cost basis in fiat. I only care about calculating the cost basis of my base currency (XMR) in the quote currency's units (BTC).

- `Tx 1` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003929 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 2` - `buy   1 XMR at 0.003847 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 3` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003741 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 4` - `sell  3 XMR at 0.007678 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 5` - `sell  2 XMR at 0.008008 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 6` - `sell  2 XMR at 0.007912 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 7` - `buy   1 XMR at 0.007084 BTC/XMR`

This data can also be portrayed in a table:

| Tx Num | Buy Qty | Buy Cur | Sell Qty | Sell Cur | Price (BTC/XMR) | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | XMR | 0.011787 | BTC | 0.003929 | 2021-10-19 |
| 2 | 1 | XMR | 0.003847 | BTC | 0.003847 | 2021-12-15 |
| 3 | 3 | XMR | 0.011223 | BTC | 0.003741 | 2022-01-31 |
| 4 | 0.023034 | BTC | 3 | XMR | 0.007678 | 2022-09-01 |
| 5 | 0.016016 | BTC | 2 | XMR | 0.008008 | 2022-09-05 |
| 6 | 0.015824 | BTC | 2 | XMR | 0.007912 | 2022-09-08 |
| 7 | 1 | XMR | 0.007084 | BTC | 0.007084 | 2022-09-02 |

My understanding is that, following either FIFO or LIFO, the cost basis after `Day 4` would be calculated using the 3 XMR purchased either on `Day 1` or `Day 3`. What's especially interesting is: how do you calculate the cost basis after `Day 5` (which would be a combination of two distinct `buy` transactions)??

How can I calculate the cost basis for my above-described portfolio after each of the 7 days shown?

Comment: See also https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/86221/what-cost-basis-accounting-methods-are-applicable-to-virtual-currencies

Comment: As you've identified, there are many different answers to this question depending on how you are matching up buys and sells.  You'd first need to determine that answer.  Which would depend on things like whether you are trying to match the calculations of some other entity (i.e. your broker's site) or whether you are trying to match the calculations you are doing for tax purposes.

Comment: This is to help determine the best price to sell above and buy under based on current buy-in (I have X Monero and I've paid an average of Y Bitcoin for it at this point in time). This is not for tax purposes.

Comment: See also https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/20464/how-to-calculate-average-buy-price-when-you-buy-sell-and-rebuy

Comment: See also https://cointracking.info/documentation.php

Comment: Are you saying you want to use the average cost method rather than FIFO, LIFO, or any other method to match buys and sells?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "match buys and sells" -- I don't know how it's possible to "match" a buy with a sell when the buys and sells are for different quantities. I mostly just want to know *how to calculate* the cost basis for each of these methods for a complex set of buys & sells.

Comment: So you want to calculate 6 different answers on each day for the 6 different methods you've listed?  Or do you want to calculate one answer on each day?  The latter would be far more sensible in the vast majority of cases but then you'd need to tell us what algorithm you want to use.

Comment: Ideally, I want to design a spreadsheet that calculates the cost basis using *every* method (not just these 6; I believe there's more). But I'll accept an answer here on SE that provides just one..

Comment: Deposit dollars, buy XMR with dollars, sell some XMR for dollars, and buy some BTC with the dollars. Sell BTC for dollars and buy XMR with the dollars. http://kbhscape.com/kbh.htm . Now in the software, XMR could just be used in place of dollars but there would be no reportable transactions but just a reportable overall year-ending result based on the dollar value of the beginning XMR versus the dollar value of the ending XMR.

Comment: @SSpring Please read the question. I am not going to be doing any transactions with fiat, and I don't want any metrics reported in fiat (eg dollars)

Comment: The second comment says to use XMR numbers in place of dollar numbers. The cost basis of a transaction is just the number of XMR. Do a supplemental overall year-ending conversion to dollar result if wanted. In the U.S., if futures accounting can be applied, or if trader-status can be applied, then the year-ending overall dollar result is all that is required. Itemize transactions by your own method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer will show how to calculate:

1. the **average buy**,
2. the **average sell**, and
3. the **break-even price**

These calculations were determined using cointracking.info

Unfortunately, it's still a mystery how one would calculate the cost basis using FIFO or LIFO. I welcome other answers that show how to do these calculations :)

### Transaction 1

- `Tx 1` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003929 BTC/XMR`

After the first day, the calculations are simple.

You currently have a total of 3 XMR.

You spent a total of `(3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) = 0.011787 BTC`

###### Average Buy

For the "Average Buy," we want to know the average price that we paid (in BTC) for each 1 coin of XMR.

To calculate the "Average Buy," we take the sum of the all of our *weighted* buys (obtained by multiplying the quantity of XMR bought by the price of 1 XMR in BTC) and divide it by the sum of the quantity of XMR bought.

> **Note** For the "Average Buy" do not include any *sell* transactions

The algorithm for this is

> [ (tx<sub>1</sub> buy qty) * (tx<sub>1</sub> price) + (tx<sub>2</sub> buy qty) * (tx<sub>2</sub> price) + ... + (tx<sub>n</sub> buy qty) * (tx<sub>n</sub> price) ] / [ (tx<sub>1</sub> buy qty) + (tx<sub>2</sub> buy qty) + ... + (tx<sub>n</sub> buy qty) ]

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) ] = 0.003929 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your average buy at this point is `0.003929 BTC/XMR`**

###### Average Sell

For the "Average Sell," we want to know the average price that we sold (in BTC) for each 1 coin of XMR.

To calculate the "Average Sell," we take the sum of the all of our *weighted* sells (obtained by multiplying the quantity of XMR sold by the price of 1 XMR in BTC) and divide it by the sum of the quantity of XMR sold.

> **Note** For the "Average Sell" do not include any *buy* transactions

The algorithm for this is

> [ (tx<sub>1</sub> sell qty) * (tx<sub>1</sub> price) + (tx<sub>2</sub> sell qty) * (tx<sub>2</sub> price) + ... + (tx<sub>n</sub> sell qty) * (tx<sub>n</sub> price) ] / [ (tx<sub>1</sub> sell qty) + (tx<sub>2</sub> sell qty) + ... + (tx<sub>n</sub> sell qty) ]

At this point, you haven't sold anything. There is no average sell price.

###### Break-Even Price

For the "Break-Even Price," we want to know at what price you would need to sell all of your XMR in order to break even (profit = 0 BTC).

To calculate the "Break-Even Price," we take the sum of the all of our *weighted* buys *and sells* (obtained by multiplying the quantity of XMR bought/sold by the price of 1 XMR in BTC) and divide it by the sum of the quantity of XMR bought/sold.

> **Note** The Break-Even Price is very similar to the "Average Buy" and "Average Sell," except that it includes both buy *and* sell transactions.

The algorithm for this is

> [ (tx<sub>1</sub> qty) * (tx<sub>1</sub> price) + (tx<sub>2</sub> qty) * (tx<sub>2</sub> price) + ... + (tx<sub>n</sub> qty) * (tx<sub>n</sub> price) ] / [ (tx<sub>1</sub> qty) + (tx<sub>2</sub> qty) + ... + (tx<sub>n</sub> qty) ]

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) ] = 0.003929 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your break-even price at this point is `0.003929 BTC/XMR`**

### Transaction 2

- `Tx 1` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003929 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 2` - `buy   1 XMR at 0.003847 BTC/XMR`

After the second transaction, you've completed two buy transactions and currently hold a total of `3 XMR + 1 XMR = 4 XMR`.

###### Average Buy

For the "Average Buy," we simply sum how much we spent on XMR purchases (in bitcoin) and divide it by the sum of XMR that we own.

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.003847 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (1 XMR) ] = 0.0039085 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your average buy at this point is `0.0039085 BTC/XMR`**

> **Note** that the previous buy price was `0.003929 BTC/XMR`. It makes sense that this new average buy price is slightly lower because our second purchase was made at a slightly less expensive price.

###### Average Sell

At this point, you haven't sold anything. There is no average sell price.

###### Break-Even Price

For the "Break-Even," we simply sum how much we spent or received on *all* XMR purchases & sales (in bitcoin) and divide it by the sum of XMR that we've bought and sold.

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.003847 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (1 XMR) ] = 0.0039085 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your break-even price at this point is `0.0039085 BTC/XMR`**

### Transaction 3

- `Tx 1` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003929 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 2` - `buy   1 XMR at 0.003847 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 3` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003741 BTC/XMR`

After the third transaction, you've completed three buy transactions and currently hold a total of `3 XMR + 1 XMR + 3 XMR = 7 XMR`.

###### Average Buy

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.003847 BTC/XMR) + (3 XMR) * (0.003741 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (1 XMR) + (3 XMR) ] = 0.003836714 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your average buy at this point is `0.003836714 BTC/XMR`**

###### Average Sell

At this point, you haven't sold anything. There is no average sell price.

###### Break-Even Price

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.003847 BTC/XMR) + (3 XMR) * (0.003741 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (1 XMR) + (3 XMR) ] = 0.003836714 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your break-even price at this point is `0.003836714 BTC/XMR`**

### Transaction 4

- `Tx 1` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003929 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 2` - `buy   1 XMR at 0.003847 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 3` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003741 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 4` - `sell  3 XMR at 0.007678 BTC/XMR`

After the fourth transaction, you've completed three buy transactions and one sell transaction. You currently hold a total of `3 XMR + 1 XMR + 3 XMR - 3 XMR = 4 XMR`.

###### Average Buy

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.003847 BTC/XMR) + (3 XMR) * (0.003741 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (1 XMR) + (3 XMR) ] = 0.003836714 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your average buy at this point is `0.003836714 BTC/XMR`**

> **Note** Because this sell transaction is not computed in the "Average Buy," there is no change from the previous transaction's average buy of `0.003836714 BTC/XMR`

###### Average Sell

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.007678 BTC/XMR) / [ (3 XMR) ] = 0.007678 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your average sell at this point is `0.007678 BTC/XMR`**

###### Break-Even Price

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.003847 BTC/XMR) + (3 XMR) * (0.003741 BTC/XMR) - (3 XMR) * (0.007678 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (1 XMR) + (3 XMR) - (3 XMR) ] = 0.00095575 BTC/XMR
```

> **Note** For the sell transactions, we *subtract* both the weighted transaction amount from the top of the denominator and the quantity from the bottom of the denominator

Therefore, **your break-even price at this point is `0.00095575 BTC/XMR`**

> **Note** that because we've now had our first sell transaction, the "Average Buy" and "Break-Even" prices begin to diverge.

### Transaction 5

- `Tx 1` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003929 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 2` - `buy   1 XMR at 0.003847 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 3` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003741 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 4` - `sell  3 XMR at 0.007678 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 5` - `sell  2 XMR at 0.008008 BTC/XMR`

After the fifth transaction, you've completed three buy transactions and two sell transaction. You currently hold a total of `3 XMR + 1 XMR + 3 XMR - 3 XMR - 2 XMR = 2 XMR`.

###### Average Buy

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.003847 BTC/XMR) + (3 XMR) * (0.003741 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (1 XMR) + (3 XMR) ] = 0.003836714 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your average buy at this point is `0.003836714 BTC/XMR`**

###### Average Sell

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.007678 BTC/XMR) + (2 XMR) * (0.008008 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (2 XMR) ] = 0.00781 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your average sell at this point is `0.00781 BTC/XMR`**

###### Break-Even Price

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.003847 BTC/XMR) + (3 XMR) * (0.003741 BTC/XMR) - (3 XMR) * (0.007678 BTC/XMR) - (2 XMR) * (0.008008 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (1 XMR) + (3 XMR) - (3 XMR) - (2 XMR) ] = -0.0060965 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your break-even price at this point is `-0.0060965 BTC/XMR`**

> **Note** Your break-even price becomes negative here because you've been so profitable that, even if the value of XMR drops to zero, you'd still have net positive gains

### Transaction 6

- `Tx 1` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003929 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 2` - `buy   1 XMR at 0.003847 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 3` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003741 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 4` - `sell  3 XMR at 0.007678 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 5` - `sell  2 XMR at 0.008008 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 6` - `sell  2 XMR at 0.007912 BTC/XMR`

After the sixth transaction, you've completed three buy transactions and three sell transaction of equal amounts. You currently hold a total of `3 XMR + 1 XMR + 3 XMR - 3 XMR - 2 XMR - 2 XMR = 0 XMR`.

###### Average Buy

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.003847 BTC/XMR) + (3 XMR) * (0.003741 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (1 XMR) + (3 XMR) ] = 0.003836714 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your average buy at this point is `0.003836714 BTC/XMR`**

###### Average Sell

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.007678 BTC/XMR) + (2 XMR) * (0.008008 BTC/XMR) + (2 XMR) * (0.007912 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (2 XMR) + (2 XMR) ] = 0.00781 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your average sell at this point is `0.00781 BTC/XMR`**

###### Break-Even Price

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.003847 BTC/XMR) + (3 XMR) * (0.003741 BTC/XMR) - (3 XMR) * (0.007678 BTC/XMR) - (2 XMR) * (0.008008 BTC/XMR) - (2 XMR) * (0.007912 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (1 XMR) + (3 XMR) - (3 XMR) - (2 XMR) - (2 XMR) ] = infinity!! BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your break-even price at this point is `infinity!! BTC/XMR`**

> **Note** Your break-even price cannot be calculated here because you've sold all your XMR and you cannot divide by zero

### Transaction 7

- `Tx 1` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003929 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 2` - `buy   1 XMR at 0.003847 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 3` - `buy   3 XMR at 0.003741 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 4` - `sell  3 XMR at 0.007678 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 5` - `sell  2 XMR at 0.008008 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 6` - `sell  2 XMR at 0.007912 BTC/XMR`
- `Tx 7` - `buy   1 XMR at 0.007084 BTC/XMR`

After the seventh transaction, you've bought and sold all your XMR for a profit, then you re-bought at a relative low. You currently hold a total of `3 XMR + 1 XMR + 3 XMR - 3 XMR - 2 XMR - 2 XMR + 1 XMR = 1 XMR`.

###### Average Buy

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.003847 BTC/XMR) + (3 XMR) * (0.003741 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.007084 XMR/BTC) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (1 XMR) + (3 XMR) + (1 XMR) ] = 0.004242625 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your average buy at this point is `0.004242625 BTC/XMR`**

###### Average Sell

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.007678 BTC/XMR) + (2 XMR) * (0.008008 BTC/XMR) + (2 XMR) * (0.007912 BTC/XMR) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (2 XMR) + (2 XMR) ] = 0.00781 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your average sell at this point is `0.00781 BTC/XMR`**

###### Break-Even Price

```
[ (3 XMR) * (0.003929 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.003847 BTC/XMR) + (3 XMR) * (0.003741 BTC/XMR) - (3 XMR) * (0.007678 BTC/XMR) - (2 XMR) * (0.008008 BTC/XMR) - (2 XMR) * (0.007912 BTC/XMR) + (1 XMR) * (0.007084 XMR/BTC) ] / [ (3 XMR) + (1 XMR) + (3 XMR) - (3 XMR) - (2 XMR) - (2 XMR) + (1 XMR) ] = -0.020933 BTC/XMR
```

Therefore, **your break-even price at this point is `-0.020933 BTC/XMR`**

Answer (score 0):

If XMR is the base currency then use XMR numbers in place of dollar numbers. The cost basis of a transaction is just the number of XMR.

If BTC is the base currency then use BTC numbers in place of dollar numbers. The cost basis of a transaction is just the number of BTC.

Do a supplemental overall year-ending conversion to dollar result if wanted.

In the U.S., forex is mark-to-market accounting but not to be included on a Form 6781, for 60/40 long-term/short-term designation, unless the forex is also available on regulated futures exchanges.

However, crypto is not mark-to-market accounting and so it might be necessary to apply for mark-to-market accounting.

But with mark-to-market accounting then the overall year-ending conversion to dollar result is all that is required. Or itemized transactions might also be required and then just use your own method along with a letter of explanation.

Well, forex goes on either "Other income" of a Form 1040 Schedule 1, or goes on a trader-status Form 4797, or goes on a Form 6781.

Crypto goes on a Form 8949
.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make any sense. I'm asking for how to calculate things, and I didn't see anything calculated. This question is also not related to taxes, so I don't know why that was mentioned.

Comment: If XMR is the base currency then use XMR numbers in place of dollar numbers. The cost basis of a position is the number of XMR. You can't have two different types of cost basis and then say that nothing is calculated.

Comment: I specifically asked for the basis in BTC. That's my main currency that I'm trying to stack. The valid answer to this question should provide the cost basis after each transaction and show how that was calculated. The reason I'm asking this question in the first place is because the internet is full of answers like yours, which are useless to actually understand how the basis is calculated.

Comment: Well, the cost basis of XMR can be in BTC with BTC used as the base currency.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you please *show* what you mean by typing out the mathematical equations after each transaction ?

Comment: In the software, deposit BTC and buy XMR. The cost basis of XMR is the number of BTC.

Comment: What "software"?

Comment: You could use the software that I linked which is easier than a spreadsheet. Or you can use some other software. Or you can work longhand. But deposit BTC numbers, buy XMR, and then the cost basis of XMR is the number of BTC.

Comment: The purpose of this question is literally to show how to "work it out longhand" so that people can know exactly what "the software" is doing. Please update your answer with the "longhand" calculations.

Comment: Deposit a number of BTC instead of a number of dollars. Buy XMR with the required number of BTC. The cost basis of the XMR is the number of BTC.

Comment: Then year-ending BTC versus year-beginning BTC can convert to a dollar gain/loss result if needed. However, deposits and withdrawals must be allowed-for. A deposit is not gain while a withdrawal is not loss.